# How to find the update that started causing display artifacts?

Tags: 16.04, display, visual-artifacts

One of the updates at the first half of July caused my Ubuntu 16.04 installation to display artifacts when connected to a Dell display through a docking station. The artifacts are showing both on the Dell display and on the laptop's display, and do not appear when the Dell display is not connected. How would you suggest finding which update caused it and revert it?

#### Some info related to the issue itself (the question is about bisecting the "bad" update, but maybe someone can find a solution to the issue directly):

Updating Intel's display driver from 01.org didn't help.

Also worth mentioning that it does not happen with another Philips display, connected to the same Dock with HDMI. Connecting the Dell display with HDMI didn't solve the issue.

The setup:

- Lenovo Yoga 720-13IKB
- Graphics card: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
- Connected to an Asus SIMPRO Dock through USB-C
- Dell P2317HI display connected to the docking station with DisplayPort/HDMI

A video showing the artifacts (throughout the first 20 seconds):
https://streamable.com/vpr6b

The recent update history from `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2018-07-07  19:06:54
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.385'
Install: libllvm6.0:amd64 (1:6.0-1ubuntu2~16.04.1, automatic)
Upgrade: libsoup-gnome2.4-1:amd64 (2.52.2-1ubuntu0.2, 2.52.2-1ubuntu0.3), libdrm-nouveau2:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (4.4.0-128.154, 4.4.0-130.156), gir1.2-soup-2.4:amd64 (2.52.2-1ubuntu0.2, 2.52.2-1ubuntu0.3), libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.2.26, 1.2.27), update-notifier-common:amd64 (3.168.8, 3.168.9), libarchive-zip-perl:amd64 (1.56-2, 1.56-2ubuntu0.1), apt:amd64 (1.2.26, 1.2.27), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1.4.0-1~16.04.1, 18.0.1-1~16.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (67.0.3396.87-1, 67.0.3396.99-1), libxatracker2:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 (1.2.26, 1.2.27), libsoup2.4-1:amd64 (2.52.2-1ubuntu0.2, 2.52.2-1ubuntu0.3), libgbm1:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (60.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 61.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libdrm2:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1), oracle-java8-set-default:amd64 (8u171-1~webupd8~0, 8u171-1~webupd8~1), rfkill:amd64 (0.5-1ubuntu3, 0.5-1ubuntu3.1), apt-utils:amd64 (1.2.26, 1.2.27), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), oracle-java8-installer:amd64 (8u171-1~webupd8~0, 8u171-1~webupd8~1), xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1~16.04.1, 2:2.99.917+git20171229-1~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1, 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4~16.04.1), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libdrm-intel1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1), firefox:amd64 (60.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 61.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), apt-transport-https:amd64 (1.2.26, 1.2.27), libdrm-radeon1:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04:amd64 (2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1, 2:1.19.6-1ubuntu4~16.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1, 1:18.0.1-1~16.04.1), libexiv2-14:amd64 (0.25-2.1ubuntu16.04.1, 0.25-2.1ubuntu16.04.2), update-notifier:amd64 (3.168.8, 3.168.9), xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:amd64 (1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1, 1:18.0.1-1~16.04.1), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1, 18.0.5-0ubuntu0~16.04.1), libdrm-common:amd64 (2.4.83-1~16.04.1, 2.4.91-2~16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-07-07  19:07:52

Start-Date: 2018-07-11  15:22:26
Commandline: apt install android-tools-adb
Requested-By: user (1000)
Install: android-tools-adb:amd64 (5.1.1r36+git20160322-0ubuntu3)
End-Date: 2018-07-11  15:22:27

Start-Date: 2018-07-15  10:39:49
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libimage-magick-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libcups2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), libimage-magick-q16-perl:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), imagemagick:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libmagickwand-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), cups-server-common:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), cups-common:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), libpng12-dev:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1, 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1), imagemagick-6.q16:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libmagickcore-6.q16-2-extra:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), cups-ppdc:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), libcupsmime1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), firefox-locale-en:amd64 (61.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 61.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), libmagickcore-6.q16-2:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libjpeg-turbo8:amd64 (1.4.2-0ubuntu3, 1.4.2-0ubuntu3.1), libcupsppdc1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), firefox:amd64 (61.0+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.2, 61.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), imagemagick-common:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libmagick++-6.q16-5v5:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), cups-bsd:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), cups-core-drivers:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), cups-daemon:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), libcupsimage2:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), cups:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), libcupscgi1:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), cups-client:amd64 (2.1.3-4ubuntu0.4, 2.1.3-4ubuntu0.5), perlmagick:amd64 (8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.11, 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.12), libpng12-0:amd64 (1.2.54-1ubuntu1, 1.2.54-1ubuntu1.1)
End-Date: 2018-07-15  10:40:06

Start-Date: 2018-07-15  10:51:00
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.730'
Upgrade: dnsmasq-base:amd64 (2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.4, 2.75-1ubuntu0.16.04.5), flashplugin-installer:amd64 (30.0.0.113ubuntu0.16.04.1, 30.0.0.134ubuntu0.16.04.1), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (1:52.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:52.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), thunderbird:amd64 (1:52.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1), dns-root-data:amd64 (2015052300+h+1, 2018013001~16.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.157.19, 1.157.20), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (1:52.8.0+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1:52.9.1+build3-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)
End-Date: 2018-07-15  10:52:16

Start-Date: 2018-07-17  11:07:13
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-install-file' sender=':1.83'
Install: libxcb-xtest0:amd64 (1.11.1-1ubuntu1, automatic)
End-Date: 2018-07-17  11:07:14

Start-Date: 2018-07-18  11:32:40
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Upgrade: libpolkit-gobject-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1), libpolkit-agent-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1), libpolkit-backend-1-0:amd64 (0.105-14.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1), policykit-1:amd64 (0.105-14.1, 0.105-14.1ubuntu0.1)
End-Date: 2018-07-18  11:32:44

Start-Date: 2018-07-19  16:49:39
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: user (1000)
Upgrade: snapd:amd64 (2.32.9, 2.33.1ubuntu2), squashfs-tools:amd64 (1:4.3-3ubuntu2.16.04.1, 1:4.3-3ubuntu2.16.04.2), gnome-software:amd64 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.10, 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), python-apt-common:amd64 (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2), ubuntu-software:amd64 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.10, 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64 (66.0.3359.181-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, 67.0.3396.99-0ubuntu0.16.04.2), ubuntu-core-launcher:amd64 (2.32.9, 2.33.1ubuntu2), oracle-java8-set-default:amd64 (8u171-1~webupd8~1, 8u181-1~webupd8~1), oracle-java8-installer:amd64 (8u171-1~webupd8~1, 8u181-1~webupd8~1), gnome-software-common:amd64 (3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.10, 3.20.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.11), python3-apt:amd64 (1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.1, 1.1.0~beta1ubuntu0.16.04.2)
End-Date: 2018-07-19  16:50:45
```

Answer (score 0):

This could likely be caused by an upgrade of these packages (all related to graphics) of the upgrade of the 2018-07-07

```
libdrm-nouveau2:amd64
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04
libegl1-mesa
libdrm-amdgpu1
libdrm2:amd64
libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04:amd64
xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64
libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64
libdrm-intel1:amd64
libdrm-radeon1:amd64
xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:amd64
mesa-va-drivers:amd64
libdrm-common:amd64
libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64
```

So you could try to reinstall the old version with

```
sudo apt install libdrm-nouveau2:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1 libglapi-mesa:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04:amd64=1.4.0-1~16.04.1 libegl1-mesa:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 libdrm-amdgpu1:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1 libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 libdrm2:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04:amd64=2:2.99.917+git20170309-0ubuntu1~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04:amd64=2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 libdrm-intel1:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1 libdrm-radeon1:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-legacy-hwe-16.04:amd64=2:1.19.5-0ubuntu2~16.04.1 mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04:amd64=1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04:amd64=1:7.10.0-1~16.04.1 mesa-va-drivers:amd64=17.2.8-0ubuntu0~16.04.1 libdrm-common:amd64=2.4.83-1~16.04.1
```

but it might break dependancies (so you are on your own to fix that) or not work because I have not tested it (meaning, you need to use another command to reinstall the old version)

Comment: I get `version not found` with this command

Comment: Check that the package are in your cache `/var/cache/apt/archives/`. If yes, try to use `dpkg -i` or any other command to install those said packages

Comment: Unfortunately they are not, since it is a relatively fresh install and so this is the first time most of these packages were upgraded